# C++ Object Undeclared Identifier

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm no newbie to code, but I am to Visual Studios. For the life of me, I cannot figure out why I am getting the following syntax errors. The code is refusing to allow me to declare an object `Match m = new Match();`.

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include "Match.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

const int NUM_TRIALS = 100000;

int main()
{
    Match m = new Match();
    printf("Program begin\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        m = Match();
        printf("%s ... %s\n", m.to_str123().c_str(), m.printStr.c_str());
    }
    printf("Program end.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Match.h**

```
#pragma once
#ifndef MATCH_H_
#define MATCH_H_
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

#define HERO_PER_TEAM 3
#define NUM_HERO 10

class Match {
public:
    Match();
    ~Match();

    string to_str123();
    string printStr();

private:
    char teams[HERO_PER_TEAM * 2];
};

#endif
```

**Error Messages**

```
Error   C2065   'Match': undeclared identifier  ConsoleApplication1 
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'm' ConsoleApplication1 
Error   C2065   'm': undeclared identifier  ConsoleApplication1 
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'Match'    ConsoleApplication1
Error   C2065   'm': undeclared identifier  ConsoleApplication1 
Error   C3861   'Match': identifier not found   ConsoleApplication1 
Error   C2065   'm': undeclared identifier  ConsoleApplication1 
Error   C2228   left of '.to_str123' must have class/struct/union   ConsoleApplication1 
Error   C2228   left of '.c_str' must have class/struct/union   ConsoleApplication1 
Error   C2228   left of '.printStr' must have class/struct/union    ConsoleApplication1
```

Comment: it can only be C **or** C++, so I'm removing the C tag.

Comment: Use either `#pragma once` or macro include guards, not both.

Comment: `Match m = new Match();` --> `Match* mPtr = new Match();`. or simply `Match m;`

Comment: `using namespace std;` in a header can ruin your day in many ways. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice

Comment: `m.printStr.c_str()` should be `m.printStr().c_str()`. That and the pointer confusion wrap up all of the problems except the missing definition of `Match`, which I'm unable to reproduce.

Comment: Yes the object identifier is what is confusing the hell out of me. I rarely us VS and when I do the weirdest stuff happens to me.

Comment: ***Error   C2065   'Match': undeclared identifier  ConsoleApplication1*** is caused by the following: `#include "stdafx.h"` must be the first non comment / non blank line of your cpp file.

Answer (score 3):

You are using new to assign a value to a non-pointer type. If you want a pointer you can use:

```
Match* m = new Match();
```

otherwise, just declare it like this:

```
Match m;
```

Since `m` is not recognized as an object you are getting all of the other errors too.

Also you should be able to use `#pragma once` in place of standard include guards.

Comment: Not all of the errors. `printStr` function is being used as a variable. Needs the `()`.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the new however I still continue to get <code>'Match': undeclared identifier</code> error.

Comment: That would indicate that the compiler can't find your class.  Try what I suggested by removing the standard include guards and just using `#pragma`.

Comment: Yes I that as well. I have no idea what could be causing this, VS is the worst :(

Comment: What line are you getting the undeclared identifier error on?

Comment: Match m = new Match();

Comment: That's your problem.  Its `Match m;` without the parens.  You only use `()` in this case when it is a non-default constructor (has arguments). Although you still would in the case of `Match* m = new Match();`.

Comment: Even when my main.cpp file is contains only 
int main()
{
 Match m;
}
.. I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you move `#include "stdafx.h"` to the first line of your cpp file?

Answer (score 1):

The `new` operator returns a pointer to an initialized object, using the given constructor. What you're doing here is java syntax. To do it properly you have to create a pointer to an object of that type: `Match *m = new Match();`. Then instead of using `m.printStr` you'd use `m->printStr` and you must not forget to delete the memory allocated using `delete m`. Or you could simply allocate it on the stack using `Match m();` or `Match m = Match()`. Then you can still use the form `m.printStr` and you don't need to worry about deleting the memory.